# How can I pass into a directive a service?

Tags: angularjs

The following directive works when I call it from a controller `as test`:

```
app.directive('codeblock', function() {
    return {
    scope: true,  // Need to change this but not sure how
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '<div>{{ test.stateService.message }}</div>'
    };
});
```

The following directive works when I call it from a controller `as abc`:

```
app.directive('codeblock', function() {
    return {
    scope: true,  // Need to change this but not sure how
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '<div>{{ abc.stateService.message }}</div>'
    };
});
```

How can I change the directive so I can pass in: `test.stateService` or `abc.stateService`. I think the directive needs to look like this:

```
app.directive('codeblock', function() {
    return {
    scope: true,  // use a child scope that inherits from parent
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '<div>{{ stateService.message }}</div>'
    };
});
```

But I do not understand how to do change the directive so I can pass in the stateService and how I would need to call it. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a `service`, pass it in just like you would pass a service to a controller.

```
app.directive('codeblock', ['stateService', function(stateService) {
    return {
      scope: true,  // use a child scope that inherits from parent
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: 'false',
      template: '<div>{{ stateService.message }}</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.stateService = stateService;
      }
    };
}]);
```

Services are singletons, there's no need to pass it via the DOM.

Comment: When I call this directive do I need to do <codeblock /> or <codeblock> is okay ?

Comment: Neither. You have `restrict: 'A'` which means the directive can only be used as an attribute. `<div codeblock />`. If you want to use it as an element you need `restrict: 'E'`. If you do that, I've had problems with self-closing custom tags and HTML5 validators, and personally prefer `<codeblock></codeblock>`.

Comment: Do note, if you plan to support IE8 there's extra steps you need to take to be able to use it as an element. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie. Personally I think there are more drawbacks than advantages with using directives as elements but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: So it would be okay to call it like this: <div id="codeblock" data-codeblock></div> ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ It should be, yes, but since you're asking I suspect something went wrong when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass what you want in to the directive,

```
app.directive('codeblock', function() {
    return {
    scope: {
        stateService:"="
     },  // use a child scope that inherits from parent
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '<div>{{ stateService.message }}</div>'
    };
});
```

And in HTML ,

```
<div codeblock  state-service="stateService"></div>
```